# Copying chart from locked sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The following piece of macro

```
'Copy the chart and paste it into the PowerPoint as a Metafile Picture
        cht.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
        activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select
```

is failing at `cht.Select` because the sheet is locked. How do I change it to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the code to

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
cht.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select
ActiveSheet.Protect "password"
```

Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unlock the sheet before copying, and lock the sheet again after copying:

```
cht.Parent.Parent.Unprotect
'Your code here
cht.Parent.Parent.Protect
```

Comment: I changed the code adding those two lines, but I get the run-time error -2147024809 (80070057) Requested shapes are locked for selection