# VBA Excel script with locked sheets

Tags: vba, excel, locking

I have a lot of VBA excel scripts which modifying the cells value. The scripts worked fine until I locked the sheets. After I locked sheets I get this error:
[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9QKE.png)

I also read here that there is a way to enable to scripts only to modify cells value, like that:

```
    For Each Sh In Worksheets
        Sh.Protect Password:="password", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Next
```

I locked sheets with this script, but It's working only until I reopen the workbook. After I closed and open again the locks on the sheet is sill active, but gives me the same error message.

What is the best solution to use script with locked sheets?

Comment: Unprotect the sheet before editing and then protect again programmatically.

Comment: check if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915492/copying-chart-from-locked-sheet

Comment: Its possible that the capital "F" in `UserInterfaceOnly` is giving you a problem (and not being recognized if `Option Explicit` is not declared)

Comment: @Ian: The other problem is with this solution, that the sheets scripts changing other sheets too, so this recursively will give me errors.

Comment: @L.Dutch: Same problem. I already tried this.

Comment: @RGA: This was a type, your were right, but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @PyVas Write a subroutine to unprotect and protect all sheets in your excel file. Call the unprotect function before the code you want to run and then call the protect function.

Comment: This is not working, because in Excel 2010 and above encryption algorythm is very slow and It takes so long protect all the sheets.